# mysql fulltext boolean search with asterix

Tags: mysql, search, boolean, full-text-search

I have a query like below:

> SELECT prd_id FROM products WHERE MATCH (prd_search_field)
>   AGAINST ('+gul* +yetistiren* +adam*' in boolean mode);

This doesn't return the rows including 'gul'.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html
The document says this.

> Then a search for '+word +the*' will likely return fewer rows than a
>   search for '+word +the':
>   The former query remains as is and requires both word and the* (a word starting with the) to be present in the document.
>   The latter query is transformed to +word (requiring only word to be present). the is both too short and a stopword, and either condition is enough to cause it to be ignored.

So as I understood the too short word condition must not be applied in my situation since I use * after each word. What's wrong with this?

As a solution I use the below query but since it's slow, I need to find another solution. Any idea would be appreciated? Thanks in advance..

> SELECT prd_id FROM products WHERE 1 AND MATCH (prd_search_field)
>   AGAINST ('+yetistiren* +adam*' in boolean mode) AND prd_search_field
>   LIKE '%gul%';

As a note ft_min_word_length=4 as default in all shared hosting environments, and I cannot change it.

Comment: Why dont you try escaping the characters?

Comment: which character should I escape? The above queries doesn't throws any error. They only return 0 row.

Comment: Nobody answered this question. I want to share my solution if it helps someone else out there.  I replaced all the words with prefix xxx while inserting, and updatating the prd_search_field. For example "gul yetistiren adam" becomes "xxxgul xxxyetistiren xxxadam". 
This made ft_min_word and ft_stop_words become disabled. completely. Everyhing works very well now.